# Possible to get images of food from the Yelp API v2?

Tags: yelp

Is it possible to get images of food using the Yelp API v2? I'm specifically looking for images like in the screenshot below:
[image: Images of food from Yelp]

Comment: I'm looking for something like this too. Were you able to find the solution?

Comment: @gibbo have you found the solution . can you share research with public

Comment: I haven't touched this project in a long time, but what I ended up doing was scraping the site using https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack .